Why did the narrator have murder on his hands in "Amazing Grace" by Jars of Clay?
The song Amazing Grace by Jars of Clay features the following lyrics:

I hitched a ride, I was a beggar
I had a murder on my hands
I needed water to rinse these stains

I'm somewhat confused by exactly what these lyrics are referring to, though. Why does the narrator refer to himself as a beggar who was responsible for a murder? And why did he "hitch a ride"?

https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/21586/was-washing-ones-hands-to-show-innocence-as-pilate-did-a-common-ritual-in-the

He could have become a beggar after murdering someone, as he was running away.

This question could be more thoroughly explored in the Christianity stack, since Jars of Clay is an evangelical band and this song is is leaning very heavily on themes specific to that community. But taking that context as a given, we can explore the literary devices at work.
The narrator of the song is recognizing that they've come to a very low point in their life. The materialistic goals they had no true value in the first place ("a mountain of fool's gold") and are now lost ("got no money, Just the faith of an empty hand"). They are acknowledging their guilt in pursuing selfish aims, and that they have neither worldly goods nor moral standing to purchase/demand forgiveness, and thus have to approach the listener (in this context, the Christian God) as a beggar pleading for unearned grace, a hitchhiker to be carried by another. The "murder" on their hands may be literal, but a more likely reading is a metaphor for both the personal harm done in life and the collective guilt of humanity that required the sacrifice of Jesus to atone for. Thus the final lines, recognizing that no water or any earthly action can wash away the stain of sin, but only accepting the blood of Christ.
The song is presented in the first person, but is clearly written as a non-specific universal perspective that any singer who shares the underlying beliefs can identify with. This is similar to John Newton's original "Amazing Grace", and indeed the entire Jars of Clay song can be seen as an expansion of the sentiment in the first lines: "Amazing grace! How sweet the sound / That saved a wretch like me!". As with many worship songs, the singers are implicitly invited to see themselves in the role they are singing. A congregant may well see themselves as a "wretch", a hitch-hiking beggar, and so on. Contrast this for example with the narrator of Johnny Cash's "Folsom Prison Blues", who is clearly a particular (albeit fictional) individual who shot a specific person in a specific place.

Thanks, excellent answer. Welcome to the site by the way - good to have you.
